# How in Scala to find unique items in List

Tags: scala

How in Scala to find unique items in List?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The most efficient order-preserving way of doing this would be to use a `Set` as an ancillary data structure:

```
def unique[A](ls: List[A]) = {
  def loop(set: Set[A], ls: List[A]): List[A] = ls match {
    case hd :: tail if set contains hd => loop(set, tail)
    case hd :: tail => hd :: loop(set + hd, tail)
    case Nil => Nil
  }

  loop(Set(), ls)
}
```

We can wrap this in some nicer syntax using an implicit conversion:

```
implicit def listToSyntax[A](ls: List[A]) = new {
  def unique = unique(ls)
}

List(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4).unique    // => List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: It is overcomplicated *now*.  Scala 2.7 didn't have anything better.

Answer (score 223):

In 2.8, it's:

```
List(1,2,3,2,1).distinct  // => List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Imho, 1 and 2 aren't unique items in the list. Only the 3 is. You create a list of unique items from the list, which is a different thing.

Comment: If that's what you want (it's usually not), go with:

List(1,2,3,2,1).groupBy(x=>x).filter(_._2.lengthCompare(1) == 0).keySet

Answer (score 14):

Roll your own uniq filter with order retention:

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3,3,4,6,5,6)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 5, 6)

scala> l.foldLeft(Nil: List[Int]) {(acc, next) => if (acc contains next) acc else next :: acc }.reverse
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5)
```

Comment: I actually enjoyed this one very much, as it allows complex filtering logic. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

If you refer to the [Rosetta Code: Create a Sequence of unique elements](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Create_a_Sequence_of_unique_elements#Scala)

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4,2,3,4,99)
val l2 = list.removeDuplicates
// l2: scala.List[scala.Int] = List(1,2,3,4,99)
```

Since `List` is immutable, you wont modify the initial `List` by calling `removeDuplicates`

Warning: as mentioned by [this tweet](http://twitter.com/harryh/statuses/4011889853)(!), this does not preserve the order:

```
scala> val list = List(2,1,2,4,2,9,3)
list: List[Int] = List(2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 9, 3)

scala> val l2 = list.removeDuplicates
l2: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 2, 9, 3)
```

For a `Seq`, that method should be available in Scala2.8, according to [ticket 929](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/929).
In the meantime, you will need to define an ad-hoc static method as the  [one seen here](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/47)

Comment: What should I do if I have Seq[String] not List?

Comment: Call `toList`, apparently :) Or, as proposed by @Synesso, use `foldLeft`.

Answer (score 7):

Imho, all the interpretations of the question are false:

> How in Scala to find unique items in List?

Given this list:

```
val ili = List (1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1)
```

the only unique item in the list is `2`. The other items aren't unique.

```
ili.toSet.filter (i => ili.indexOf (i) == ili.lastIndexOf (i))
```

will find it.

Comment: most java/scala devs would translate a question of "unique items in a given list" as "all distinct values with a given list" not "all values showing up singularly within a given list"... which is how every answer before yours interpreted it, as well as the person asking the question (who approved such an answer).  what does coming in 2+ years later and being extra sensitive on the parsing of an already answered question add?

Comment: @mujimu: I don't remember why I stumbled over the question 2 years later. Maybe sombebody closed a similar question as exact duplicate and linked here. Often I try to answer such questions for myself as an exercise before looking for the solutions of others; whether they have a similar or a better solution or whether it makes sense to publish mine. So I found that the others answered a different question. After knowing how others understood the question differently I still think that the terminology is wrong. The meaning of a sentence shouldn't be judged by majority.

Answer (score 5):

```
list.filter { x => list.count(_ == x) == 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple ad-hoc method is just to add the List to a Set, and use from there:

```
  val l = List(1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,8,8,9,9)
  val s = Set() ++ x
  println(s)
```

Produces:

```
> Set(5, 1, 6, 9, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4)
```

This works for a Seq (or any Iterable), but is not necessary in 2.8, where the removeDuplicates method will probably be more readable.  Also, not sure about the runtime performance vs a more thought-out conversion.

Also, note the lost ordering.

Answer (score 0):

list.toSet will do it since Set by definition only contains unique elements

Comment: This was pointed out, in a previous answer, over 5 years ago, What's your point?