# How to remove duplicates from list without using in inbuilt libraries such as distinct, groupBy(identity), toSet.. Etc

Tags: scala, logic, scala-collections

I wanted to write a Scala program that takes command-line args as list input and provide the output list without duplicates.
I want to know the custom implementation of this without using any libraries.

Input : 4 3 7 2 8 4 2 7 3
Output :4 3 7 2 8

Comment: What standard library methods do you consider acceptable? `foldLeft`? What about types (`List`, `Set`)? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How in Scala to find unique items in List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538598/how-in-scala-to-find-unique-items-in-list)

Comment: I must know, why not use something like `toSet` or `distinct`?

Comment: It was a assignment to write code manually without internal libraries.. I'm new to scala

Comment: Ah fair enough. You could do this quite nicely with recursion if you see my answer.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley thanks.. Your answer is helpful as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val x= List(4, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4, 2, 7, 3)
x.foldLeft(List[Int]())((l,v)=> if (l.contains(v)) l else  v :: l)
```

if you can't use contains you can do another fold

```
x.foldLeft(List[Int]())((l,v)=> if (l.foldLeft(false)((contains,c)=>if (c==v ) contains | true else contains | false)) l else  v :: l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you could do this using recursion. I've tried to lay it out in a way that's easiest to explain:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

@tailrec
def getIndividuals(in: List[Int], out: List[Int] = List.empty): List[Int] = {
  if(in.isEmpty) out
  else if(!out.contains(in.head)) getIndividuals(in.tail, out :+ in.head)
  else getIndividuals(in.tail, out)
}

val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 6, 0, 7)
val list2 = List(1)
val list3 = List()
val list4 = List(3, 3, 3, 3)

getIndividuals(list) // List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7)
getIndividuals(list2) // List(1)
getIndividuals(list3) // List()
getIndividuals(list4) // List(3)
```

This function takes two parameters, `in` and `out`, and iterates through every element in the `in` List until it's empty (by calling itself with the `tail` of `in`). Once `in` is empty, the function outputs the `out` List.

If the `out` List doesn't contain the value of `in` you are currently looking at, the function calls itself with the tail of `in` and with that value of `in` added on to the end of the `out` List.

If `out` *does* contain the value of `in` you are currently looking at, it just calls itself with the tail of `in` and the current `out` List.

**Note:** This is an alternative to the `fold` method that Arnon proposed. I personally would write a function like mine and then maybe refactor it into a `fold` function if necessary. I don't naturally think in a functional, `fold`-y way so laying it out like this helps me picture what's going on as I'm trying to work out the logic.